# Unable to get actual html in JSON result when accessing import.io API via cURL

Tags: php, json, curl, import.io

When I access the import api manually in browser by copying the api-url I get a proper json result where html fields also have html results. However, when I access the same api url via cURL with PHP I only get this in the following json result:
`{"name":"my_html","type":"HTML"}` ..so without the actual html.

I use the following function to cURL the API in php:

```
public function queryio($connectorGuid,$url,$input,$userGuid,$apiKey) {

    $io_url = "https://api.import.io/store/data/".$connectorGuid."/_query?input/webpage/url=".urlencode($url)."&_user=" . urlencode($userGuid) . "&_apikey=".$apiKey;

    $ch = curl_init();
    $timeout = 5;
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$io_url);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,$timeout);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $data;
}
```

My question is how can I get the actual html? Btw, everything works fine for other fields like text, date/time, etc.

Comment: are you using a ajax request to call to PHP ?

Comment: I would try adding a useragent to the curl request as that tends to be where many api requests fail in my experience. ie: curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'ua string here');

Comment: I've added an user agent, but no change and I'm not using an ajax request.

Comment: How do you authenticate on import.io. I have the problem that I do not get through the [authentication](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33033709/1933185). Could you solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try by removing

```
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,$timeout);
```

Comment: Sorry, no change. I'm wondering if it's somehow a setting of the import.io api...