# import.io curl simple data integration

Tags: api, curl, basic-authentication, import.io

I want to get the *simple api integration* from https://import.io via curl. I created a magic api and struggle now to get the data.

Do I use the magic api on the browser, it works fine. But with curl I get a `{"code":"NOT_AUTHORIZED"}`. Obvious that the authentication did not work.

Here's my code

```sh
#!/bin/bash

login=foo@bar.com
pass=foobar
userid=foo-bar
apikey=1f2o3o4b5a6r

curl --user $login:$pass https://api.import.io/store/data/033fbe66-13b7-4cf2-ba9c-58183a567a6f/_query?input/webpage/url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.zalando.de%2Flp-ons-wom-sale-cat-v1%2F%3Forder%3Dsale&_user=$userid&_apikey=$apikey
```

**What am I doing wrong? And how do I get it run with curl?**

Comment: https://github.com/import-io/bashtractor/blob/master/bashtractor.sh helped. With this it works

Answer (score 0):

I could get it running. Found https://github.com/import-io/bashtractor/blob/master/bashtractor.sh which solved my problem.